# Adding dll to release

Tags: c#, odac

We have completed development of our first big application in C# and we need to export it. Our app should work by just opening the .exe file. There may be some other files in Source folder, it does not matter(dll can be next to .exe). 
 We released it in Visual Studio and it work just fine on our computers, but when we move it somewhere else, it does not work. It is probably caused by ODAC (library for work with oracle database), that is not installed on other pc, where we are trying to run it. 
 How can we add the dll to release? I could not understand any answers that i've found about this topic. We dont need to merge the dll to exe, dll can be extern file. ODAC was added to project References and it has stored way on our computers, i guess that this can be the problem.
[image]

it also pop this 
[image]

It is very strange for me, that the release is runnable without any problem on our pc's but not on any other (i am sure guy who is testing it for me has .NET framework)

Comment: If the odac library is just a dll, ensure that the reference to the dll says to copy the library to the output directory.

Comment: When you say "it does not work" can you elaborate? Do you get an exception? Does some dialog box appear telling you something?

Comment: it just pop the window "Program MediTab stopped working" (i am translating it from czech)

Comment: You may want to edit your picture to blur out the username/password of a public-facing database.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the reference in question, then choose Properties. Ensure that your references are set to "Copy to Output Folder"=> Always.  That's going to put the necessary dlls in your bin folder.  Also ensure that the required version of the .NET framework is installed on the target clients.

**edit**: as @RonBeyer stated in a comment, how do you know it's not working?  I kinda glossed over that very important part in telling you how to ensure your DLLs were copied appropriately

Comment: sorry I know that this will be dumb question, but where can i find Question in Visual Studio? After right click on ODAC reference in Solution explorer i cannot find the "Copy to Output Folder"=> Always. Anyway thanks for help!

Comment: when you right click on it. select "Properties" from the right click menu.  that should open the Properties tab.  If you need to open it separately it should be under the View -> Properties Window

Comment: I dont have option "Copy to Output Folder" there. Only unlocked there are "Aliases", "Copy Local", "Embed Interop Types" and "Specific Version"

Comment: Copy Local is probably your best bet then.. I'm only used to developing in VS2010/2012 Ultimate.  It may be different on other versions.

Comment: that did not help :( but the .dll is in Release folder, thats positive

Comment: ok, so that issue is resolved. Your best best now is to start tying to trap the error that's happening and give yourself some log output when it occurs.  Any place you can wrap a big `try{} catch{}` block?

Comment: I guess it has to be caused by odac, because it is first time, when the app use this .dll and this Release runs great on our pc's.

Comment: But you confirmed the presence of the dll in your output folder. So it is clearly not just odac. There is likely a machine level dependency or configuration item outside the direct scope of your app

Comment: it falls here: OracleConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(); thats before we use configuration(and config file is in release too)

Comment: Is it possible, that if we have 64 bit version of ODAC, we cannot build application for 32 bit(86)?

Comment: Oracle is a special company, you need to install the redistributable package for it to work, it's not enough to just copy some dll's over. That means making an installer and including the necessary redistributable in it.